# Any way to trigger timeout on WaitOne() immediately?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading

In Microsoft .NET, the method [WaitOne()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public virtual bool WaitOne(
TimeSpan timeout
)
```

will return `true` if the current instance receives a signal; otherwise, `false`.

My question is, is there a way to let it return `false` even if the timeout point has not came yet?
Or
In another words, is there a way to immediately trigger a timeout on `WaitOne()` even if the real timeout point has not came?

**Update:**

The project is based on **.NET 3.5**, so the [ManualResetEventSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may not work (introduced in .NET 4). Thanks **@ani** anyway.

Comment: Do you mean to trigger it programmatically from another thread?

Comment: Yes, I think. Any thought?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't cancel the WaitOne but you could wrap it:

```
public bool Wait(WaitHandle yourEvent, WaitHandle cancelEvent, TimeSpan timeOut)
{
   WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[] { yourEvent, cancelEvent };

   // WaitAny returns the index of the event that got the signal
   var waitResult = WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles, timeOut);  

   if(waitResult == 1)
   {
       return false; // cancel!
   }

   if(waitResult == WaitHandle.WaitTimeout)
   {
       return false; // timeout
   }

   return true;
}
```

Just pass the handle you want to wait for and a handle to cancel the waiting and a time out.

**Extra**

As an extension method so it can be called in a similar way to the WaitOne:

```
public static bool Wait(this WaitHandle yourEvent, WaitHandle cancelEvent, TimeSpan timeOut)
{
   WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[] { yourEvent, cancelEvent };

   // WaitAny returns the index of the event that got the signal
   var waitResult = WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles, timeOut);  

   if(waitResult == 1)
   {
       return false; // cancel!
   }

   if(waitResult == WaitHandle.WaitTimeout)
   {
       return false; // timeout
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: @Noseratio - :) I had a similar solution `return waitResult == 0;` at first but wanted to make it very obvious that this method is 'hiding' the difference between cancel and timeout.

Comment: @Noseratio, Erno de Weerd, Thank you both for the solution!

Comment: @YuanhangGuo, no worries. You may want to learn about some other interesting APIs like `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. Although I hope you could move past .NET 3.5 to .NET 4+ and TPL very soon :)

Answer (score 6):

It appears you want to wait for a signal for a certain amount of time, while also being able to cancel the wait operation while it is in progress.

One way to achieve this is to use a  [`ManualResetEventSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) together with a cancellation token using the [`Wait(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. In this case, one of three things will happen:

1. The Wait operation will complete with true as soon as the event is signaled (before the timeout completes).
2. The Wait operation will complete with false if the event hasn't been signaled at the timeout point.
3. An OperationCanceledException will be thrown if the cancellation-token is set while the wait operation is in progress.

Comment: You are right about what I want. And ManualResetEvent seems interesting. I will try it before mark your answer. Any any other thoughts is welcomed!

Comment: May I ask how do you know about this event exists in the first place?

Comment: How do I know about this? I'm a C# programmer; it's my job to keep up with this sort of thing! :) I must have first seen it in the release notes for .NET 4, I'm guessing.

Comment: Unfortunately we are using .NET 3.5 in the project, which don't have ManualResetEventSlim. Any alternative way to do similar in .NET 3.5?

Comment: I will upvote your answer, might be helpful for others who are using .NET 4.

Answer (score 1):

If you [set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx) the event to signaled it will free the waiting thread;

Comment: Set the event will make WaitOne return true, which is not what I want. Any other thought?